# React Office Fabric UI - Node Module can't resolve itself

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4, appfabric, office-ui-fabric

`import { MultiCount } from '@uifabric/dashboard';`
I import the component and get this error.

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@uifabric/dashboard' in '/Users/jerry/Sites/office-ui-fabric-react/packages/dashboard/lib/components/Card/Layout'`

The lib/component/Card/Layout.js ln14
`import { MultiCount } from '@uifabric/dashboard';`

The imported module gets the path right, but on import it can't resolve a import from itself?
Updated the layout component to reference the folder instead of importing from itself, but that caused more build errors.

Any ideas how I can help this package self reference itself correctly? Webpack config change on the package?

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/tree/master/packages/dashboard

Comment: Hacky fix. Went to the packages src files. Changed `import @uifabric/dashboard` to `import ../../MultiCount`.  Then `dashboard/$rush update` to rebuild lib. Some imports work correctly with @uifabric/dashboard in the package. MultiCount and DashboardGridLayout are two that don't. Tho it works still looking for why import referencing itself @uifabric/component isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

`'@uifabric/dashboard$': path.join(__dirname, '../../packages/dashboard/src'),`
Adding this to alias' in webpack.serve.config.js fixed this path import issue.

`import { MultiCount } from '@uifabric/dashboard'`  works!